# extract gz files using hdfs/spark

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, gzip

I have large gzip files stored HDFS location

```
- /dataset1/sample.tar.gz --> contains 1.csv & 2.csv .... and so on
```

I would like extract

```
/dataset1/extracted/1.csv
/dataset1/extracted/2.csv
/dataset1/extracted/3.csv
.........................
.........................
/dataset1/extracted/1000.csv
```

Is there any hdfs commands that can be used to extract tar gz file (without copying to local machine) or use python/scala spark?

I tried using spark but since spark can not parallelize reading a gzipfile and the gzip file is very huge like `50GB`.
I want to split the gzip and use those for spark aggregations.

Comment: `tar.gz` is not pure `gz` and very limited.

Comment: You'd need to convert these to tar.bz2 if you did want to parallelize